# Proving one sided limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I would like to know if my solution is correct for the following limit.

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x}}$

We claim the limit is $\infty$.

For any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x\in (0,\delta)$ we have $x > 0$, $x < \delta$.

Thus $\sqrt{x} < \sqrt{\delta}$ and so $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}} > \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\delta}}$. 
Furthermore, since $x > 0$ we have $x + 2 > 2$.

Thus, from $f(x) = \dfrac{x+2}{\sqrt{x}}$ it follows
$f(x) > \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\delta}}$

Let $\delta = \dfrac{4}{\alpha^2}$

$f(x) > \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{4/\alpha^2}}$

$f(x) > \dfrac{2\alpha}{2}$

$f(x) > \alpha$

Therefore, $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \infty$ by definition.

If it is not correct, what do I need to change?

Comment: I recommend learning how to use TeX.

Comment: Michelle, you consistently refuse to use MathJax. I am downvoting this question, because there is no reason we should have to sort through your computerlike transcription. I am also recommending that it be closed as very low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, except that the part

> For any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x\in (0,\delta)$ we have $x > 0$, $x < \delta$.

is true, but meaningless. Substitute it with

> Let $\delta>0$ and suppose $x\in(0,\delta)$.

On the other hand, it's much easier. Let $\alpha>0$. Then, if $0<x<1/\alpha^2$, we have
$$
\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}>\alpha
$$

Comment: I know that statement is meaningless but would it be wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, but it adds nothing. And the next statement “Thus $\sqrt{x}<\sqrt{\delta}$…” does not follow, because you have *no* $x$ to work with, until you *assume* $x\in(0,\delta)$.

Comment: Okay but in my statement I assume that x is in that interval.

Comment: @MichelleDrolet No, read it again. In the statement “For any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$…” you can change $x$ to $y$ and it would be the same.

Comment: Okay. So saying such that for any x∈(0,δ) is not the same as stating "Assume that x∈(0,δ)"